React-admin, How to create a Form and get the form values using react-admin?
Am new to react-admin, I have created a form and try to get form values while onsubmit. Am getting an empty object {}.
Am trying to achieve two things,

onSubmit to get form values.
Whichever form elements are showing in the screen, for example if show useState is false, then the onSubmit i should only get the first field value. Lets say if show is true i should get both field values in onSubmit function.

Please provide your guidance or suggestions am stuck here so long, and dont know what am doing wrong. Thanks.
Code:
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Create, Form, TextInput } from "react-admin";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const CreateFormList = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const defaultValues = { author: "suresh", title: "you can" };

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    shouldUnregister: true,
  });

  const onsubmitHandler = (data: any) => {
    console.log("form submit values", data);
  };
  return (
    <Create>
      <Form
        defaultValues={defaultValues}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onsubmitHandler)}
      >
        <TextInput source="title" />
        {show && <TextInput source="author" />}
        <Button type="submit" label="submit" />
      </Form>
    </Create>
  );
};

export default CreateFormList;



The problem is that the useForm() call only makes sense inside form itself (usually in a component inside form). You can create your own <MyButton> component (a wrapper for <Button>) and call useForm() inside it. Please note that there is a special component <SaveButton> to save form.

Hi @MaxAlex, it s not working as expected still am getting undefined as i showed in the question. Also the way of import and use useForm()  is making me confuse. I followed the https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/ this method. THey are importing inside the component and trying to fetch the values . The same i tired its not working. am trying this last two days dont find any proper blog or video. please help

version am using -  "react-admin": "^4.8.1", and "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",

Can you explain in more detail how you want to use form values?

Perhaps it will be enough for you to use :
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inp

Hi @MaxAlex am currently trying to just create a form using react-admin and get those values. I edited my code you can take a look. Am now ended up different error.

am trying to follow this page to create a small form https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.8/EditTutorial.html

You are using the wrong example from the description, this is an example without using the react-admin capabilities.

oh , no but they are given this link as Creation and deletion page. THe problem am facing is not able to understand how  all functionality working under the react-admin syntax the above i code i added still throwing that uncaught null error navigator. I want to create a simple form with  validation but could not achieve it since 2 days.

Could you please check the question now, i reframed and added the code. not sure whats wrong in the code. the useForm is not at all  working in the code.

You still have the same error that I described in the original answer.
Look at the following example, it is closer to what you want to do:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Form.html#onsubmit

can you please please share the simple snippet how to call the hook useForm() inside Form component. I tried ended up an error couple of days back hook cannot call inside the function error. Also if i replaced the Form to SimpleForm am able to the get the onSubmit form values. But failed with the above code. Could you please modify at least my code how to call the useForm.

Am sharing my own answer, I could achieve/resolved my issues using couple of props shared the code below &
as of now I could not invoke useForm() hook.
Code:
import { Button, Create, Form, TextInput } from "react-admin";

const CreateFormList = () => {
  // Default value i added one more prop , but in my html elements i dont have any Ui for author property.
  // shouldUnregister ={true} is removing when user onSubmit it only added html elements which are present is screen that moment.
  const defaultValues = { author: "suresh", title: "you can" };

  return (
    <Create>
      <Form
        defaultValues={defaultValues}
        shouldUnregister={true}
        onSubmit={(data) => {
          console.log("data", data);
        }}
      >
        <TextInput source="title" />
         
        <Button
          type="submit"
          label="submit"
        />
      </Form>
    </Create>
  );
};

export default CreateFormList;

